# Plotting confusion matrix correctly

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import load_model


plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
# summarize history for loss
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

I am getting error while trying to plot confusion matrix for the below code snippet

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
pred = model.predict(X_test)
pred = np.argmax(pred,axis = 1) 
y_true = np.argmax(y_test,axis = 1)
```

The error for the above snippet say "NameError: name 'model' is not defined"

```
CM = confusion_matrix(y_true, pred)
from mlxtend.plotting import plot_confusion_matrix
fig, ax = plot_confusion_matrix(conf_mat=CM ,  figsize=(5, 5))
plt.show()
```

The error for the above snippet says "NameError: name 'y_true' is not defined"

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUBDs.png)

Comment: Hello! As a long-time user of this site, your question has shown up in my review queue. I'm afraid it's a bit of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem): you're asking how to "plot the confusion matrix", but your confusion about the error messages indicates that you don't understand Python well enough yet to use it for ML tasks. (To see what I mean, try running this from a command prompt: `python -c "print(model)"`. ) No judgment here (I was a beginner myself not so long ago), but I recommend that you read an introductory book on Python before attempting to use it for ML.

Answer (score 0):

`y_true` is not defined because the previous cell (where the `model` error occurs) does not complete. As you define `y_true` in the same cell where the `model not defined` error occurs, the cell doesn't execute the rest of the lines, hence `y_true` is not defined.

The first error then, `model not defined` is happening because you haven't assigned anything to the variable `model`. This should be fixed first i.e. :

```
model = load_model(<filepath to your saved model>)
```